# How can I run JUNITs in Eclipse when there is a dependency of EBean enhancing models?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to execute junits in a project where the stack is playframework with java, I'm able to run the test by calling `sbt test` but I would like run the junits in eclipse IDE but keeps showing errors because the models are NOT enhanced.

I saw that there is a plugin for eclipse, but it didn't work for me. Do you guys know to do accomplish running that junits in eclipse?

As a not I'm a noobie using playframework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I found that there are two eclipse plugins to enable the EBean enhancer and I was using the wrong one.

This link really help me to understand which version of EBean I was using in my project https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean

If you are using EBean version from 4.x to 7.x, install the following plugin http://ebean-orm.github.io/eclipse/update-4.11.2

If you are using EBean version 10.3.x, then install  http://ebean-orm.github.io/eclipse/update

Hope this helps to someone in the future...